# org.hibernate.TransientObjectException:Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am farily new to Hibernate and here i am stuck with a transientexception. Please help.

Exception occured while saving the object `Location` object references an unsaved--transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: `<City object>; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`

I am getting above exeption when i am trying to save data into my location table which has a City object with all its elements referring to null.

```
Location object       
   private String LocationAddress;  
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "CITYID")
   private City city;


City
   private String cityName;
   private int cityId;
```

In Location table `CityID` is nullable field because `city` is not a required field. And we have a city table which is a static table so we dont want to insert data in City table.
Now when we are storing Location object. It stores data fine if City object has some values like some city. But throws exception when object contains a blank object(`cityName` and `cityId` are null)

Please help.

Example scenario

```
Successful
      Location 
       locationAddress = "test Address"
        city 
           cityId="1"
           cityName="testCity"

Failure
      Location 
           locationAddress = "test Address"
           city 
               cityId=null
               cityName=null
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044913/hibernate-exception-help-transientobjectexception

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing your code, but it sounds like you are not saving your `City` before saving your `Location` class. You have two options for persisting:

You can use the `@Cascade` annotation to have the insert cascade from the parent to the child. Doing this, you can just persist the `Location` class and Hibernate will take care of the rest.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CITYID")
@Cascade(CascadeType.PERSIST)  //Or ALL if you want Updates, Deletes to go to
private City city;
```

More on `@Cascade` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html).

If you don't want to do that, you will need to explicitly persist the `City` class before saving the `Location`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about where you are trying to store a `City` class with null identifiers. @Yair is right, you are going to need to set `city` to null. If you don't want to do that programmatically, you can do it with a `@PrePersist` annotation on a method in `Location` like: `@PrePersist public void prePersist() { if(city.cityId == null) city = null; }`. Then it should save, and as long as the `city_id` column is in the Location table, Hibernate will just ignore it when it loads that object again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to save a `Location` instance that actually refers **no** `City`, then you should have `Location.City` refer to `null`, rather than creating a `City` instance of which fields are `null`.

(a `City` instance of which fields are `null` is regarded by Hibernate as if you want a new record in `cities` table of which columns values are `null` - which doesn't make much sense)

Comment: @ yair, City object sometimes have value and sometime not and this is govern by JSF beans so i am not able to make it null until and unless i put a if check..... However making it null is also not solving the problem... when i make it null hibernate start looking for city object.

Comment: @user1422423 if `Location.City` is `null`, Hibernate has no object to look for... Unless you're doing something peculiar when you're saving. Can you show how do you save the `Location` object?